# How can I stop DEVENV because I can't install Umbraco...thoughts?

Tags: umbraco, devenv

I have Umbraco. I'm trying to install it.

I get as far as the "I agree" page and WHAMO, the program says that devenv needs to be stopped first. I know what devenv is: it's Visual Studio.

It's stopped, killed, not running and I cannot find devenv ANYWHERE in Task Manager, Services, nowhere.

Please help....

Thanks,

Comment: How is it that you are trying to install it? WebMatrix? Web Platform Installer? Manually?

Comment: I found the problem on the MSDN website: Microsoft's answer is: RESTART YOUR COMPUTER. Unbelievable.

Comment: its visual studio .exe file do check visual studio running or not.